# Writing recipes inside ifeq block in Makefiles

Tags: linux, makefile

I am relatively new to Makefiles.
I have the following (simplified) code as part of my Makefile.
I wish to know if, target and the recipe can be declared inside
else statement. Is this valid to write recipe inside ifeq block.
If not can you suggest how to improve it.

```
CUR_PI_VERSION:= abc
CUR_GIT_VERSION:= cde

LAST_PI_VERSION:= bbc
LAST_GIT_VERSION:= cde

$(info $$CUR_GIT_VERSION is [${CUR_GIT_VERSION}])
$(info $$CUR_PI_VERSION is [${CUR_PI_VERSION}])

$(info $$LAST_GIT_VERSION is [${LAST_GIT_VERSION}])
$(info $$LAST_PI_VERSION is [${LAST_PI_VERSION}])

ABC_AG := ./abc_ag.py
ABC_KG := ./abc_kg.vhd
ABC_OC := ./abc_ef.txt

ifeq ($(CUR_PI_VERSION)@$(CUR_GIT_VERSION),$(LAST_PI_VERSION)@$(LAST_GIT_VERSION))
|   #echo "Everything matched, so don't need the make top"
else
# is this valid !!!  
.PHONY: $(ABC_KG)
$(ABC_AG) $(ABC_KG) $(ABC_OC):
    printf "\t TEST \n"
endif


clean: clean_fpi
clean_fpi:
    @rm -f $(ABC_KG); \
|   rm -f $(ABC_OC); \
|   rm -f $(ABC_AG);
```

Thanks. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what those `|` characters are at the beginning of lines?

Comment: The answer to your question is sure, it's fine to add any make operations inside an `ifeq` block.  That's what it's for.  Of course you must always keep in mind that `ifeq` is parsed _as the makefile is read in_ and so the condition cannot contain any references to automatic variables like `$@` etc. but you are not doing that here so it's fine.

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist for clarification on ifeq. `|` shouldn't be there, it has to do with my vim settings for indentation.